# Duration of charge held by High Voltage Components

Tags: electrical

How long can a High Voltage Capacitor in a Electric Oven hold a charge after the oven has been unplugged?

Comment: [This answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/25650/11080) over on [Electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Technically it could hold a charge for years but that's not in real world scenarios. Most likely it will be safe in 2-3 days. I'd still short it before touching it, screwdrivers are cheaper than replacement hands. Depending on how it is wired, shorting the disconnected terminals of the device - NOT THE CAP YET - together will aid a bit.

A fully charged capacitor in TVs, Ovens, etc. can cause cardiac arrest, removed a finger, weld/arc and screwdriver tip to dust; so if you don't have time to wait, still wait 2-3 days if you have time to wait, wait a week.

Comment: Wait a week and short it anyway, unless you've gotten tired of life. For tube monitors (tv, etc.) we had a shorting stick that had a probe on the end and a ground lead that passed through a healthy wattage resistor (0.5-1.0 MOhm) to reduce the discharge current. Basically the way it works is that the moment you get used to ignoring safety and thinking something's set long enough is the day you meet the perfect capacitor attached to the perfect HV diode. If you're lucky, your arm will merely be numb as it grounded through your shoulder.